# Can I add many DataObjects to another on a single go in silverstripe 3.3?

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have to add many Product dataobjects to one invoice/quote dataobject on one go. So basically- I need a form where i input all the Invoice details and then have a button to add a new product object till i have added all the products from the front end. I have silverstripe knowledge but do not know how i can achieve this, but I know it is possible

I have tried to use gridfields and multiforms since there are other objects i need to add at the same time too. All the others add, and i can add one product at a time but i cannot add more than one at once. I have also thought of making a seperate page/form to add products to a invoice one by one, but that will be time consuming for the team to do

If you can please send me in the right direction it will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to do something like this... note I've done this before but this code isn't tested it is to describe the approach...

1) in the Form function add as many instances as required but change the name of each field with an index.

```
$fields = FieldList::create();

for($i=1; $i < 10; $i++) {

    $fields->push(LiteralField::create('p'.$i,'<h1>Product '.$i.'</h1>'));

    foreach (singleton('Product')->getFrontendFields() as $field) {
        $fields->push($field);
        $field->setName($field->getName().'_'.$i);
    }
}
```

Then the same in the action / processing function... creating or updating the relevant product dataobjects...

```
for($i=1; $i < 10; $i++) {
    foreach (singleton('Product')->getFrontendFields() as $field)
        $arrProductData[$field->getName()] = $data[$field->getName().'_'.$i];

    if (!$product = Product::get()->ByID($arrProductData['ID']
        $product = Product::create();

    $product->update($arrProductData);
}
```

The form can have javascript added to it so that it hides uncompleted fields and shows a new one as you complete the last.

You can also use the above to have many different object types in a silverstripe form.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Sir! Makes complete sense and will definately help with this